# Illegal file name for PGFPlots. How to fix?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[table/x index=0,
                 table/col sep=comma]
        \addplot table[y index=1]{phase cw γ=0.0000 i\_osc=0.6000 ω=0.0500 α=0.1000 T\_max=40, phase.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following error message: `Undefined control sequence. \end{tikzpicture}`. Clear enough that it is caused by the Greek letters in the table file name. Is there a way to use this file without renaming? `\detokenize` does not help, resulting in `Could not read table file` error.

Comment: Exactly from where do you have that the mandatory argument for `\addplot table` can look like this? I have never seen it specified like this.

Comment: In the manual, it's always `datafile.dat`. I have not seen a word about allowed names.

Comment: Try with utf8 instead of utf8x.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, even worse: `Error: Unicode char γ (U+3B3) not set up for use with LaTeX.` and several similar errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer probably even knows *why* my answer works... ;-)

Comment: Not really related but if you want to use greek + utf8: load LGR encoding to declare the greek (with e.g. \usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}) utf8x is basically incompatible with the standard system and should be avoided.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yeah, I've heard of it. I have an English text with some formulas (that's clear) and the files named like that. With @Rmano's approach, `utf8` without `x` if sufficient, as the answer shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a file named `γ_ ω.csv` with the following content:

```
0, 1
1, 2
2, 4
```

In `pdflatex` (TeXLive 2019 up-to-date, on a Linux machine) this works:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[table/x index=0,
                 table/col sep=comma]
         \addplot table[y index=1]{\detokenize{"γ_ ω.csv"}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with `lualatex` and `\xelatex` the much simpler

```latex
   \addplot table[y index=1]{γ_ ω.csv};
```

works too. I think that in general using `\_` is wrong.

Comment: Wow! Apparently, both `\detokenize` and quotation marks are required. Thanks!